# jquery datatables default sort not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a 4 column table, I want the first 3 columsn to be sortable by the user, but not the 4th, this is working fine. I also want the 3rd column to sort in ASC order by default. This part isn't working, I cant get any of the columns to sort by default and can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".table-sortable").dataTable({
    aaSorting: [],
    bPaginate: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bSortable: true,
    bRetrieve: true,
    aoColumnDefs: [
        { "aTargets": [ 0 ], "bSortable": true },
        { "aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": true },
        { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "asSorting": [ "asc" ], "bSortable": true },
        { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSortable": false }
    ]
}); 
});
```

Here's what I've been working from: http://datatables.net/usage/columns

Comment: I did figure out what IS happening, is now its not allowing that type of sort on column 3. I tried adding "desc", "asc", "asc" but no success.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should get you what you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table-sortable").dataTable({
        aaSorting: [[2, 'asc']],
        bPaginate: false,
        bFilter: false,
        bInfo: false,
        bSortable: true,
        bRetrieve: true,
        aoColumnDefs: [
            { "aTargets": [ 0 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSortable": false }
        ]
    }); 
});
```

The key is the `aaSorting` option. For some reason it's not in his 'main' Usage pages... you can find it here though http://datatables.net/ref

Comment: @turbo2oh: Glad you've got it working. DataTables is a great plugin

Comment: Hi, anyone got aaSorting with if aTargets use classnames instead of column indices?

Comment: The only way I've gotten it to work with class names instead of column indices if with the following: 'aaSorting': [[$('.desc').index(), 'desc']] where '.desc' of the class on the column th I'd like to sort.

Comment: not working for me, 
only "bSortable": true -- showing sorting icon,
"bSortable": false -- not showing icon.
But functionality not working.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out why "order" wasn't working for me like it showed here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html. aaSorting worked perfectly as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me. Thanks.. Initially I was using `'order':[2,'desc']` which was not working..Correct option is **aaSorting**

eg;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').DataTable({
        aaSorting: [[0, 'desc']]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please add this text as it should be, as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This indeed works. The documentation I could find that seemed "official" showed "order" as the proper parameter, but aaSorting worked for me. 

Anyone know why "order" doesn't work? Bad docs?

Comment: I haven't used data tables in a while now but as I remember aaSorting was pre-1.10 and order is >=1.10